# How to find/calculate time taken for synchronization in SQL Always on AG?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I have an SQL Always On Availability Group (AG) with 4 Servers (Replica).

I'm going to add a new database (about 200GB) in the AG.

I want to measure the time taken for the dB synchronization (Complete & for the First Time), in remaining 3 servers.

How do I get this done ?

Environment: SQL Always On 2016. AG.

Comment: Are you using direct seeding, or backup/restore?

Comment: Using Automatic seeding mode.

Comment: Sure, start here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5341/monitoring-sql-server-availability-group-direct-seeding/